# Call JavaScript via Java

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

**Initial situation :**

I have a JavaFX program where I put data into a MYSQL database, enter and save it.
In the JavaFX program, I have a PDF displayed via WebView using JavaScript. From the JavaFX programm i call the html to open the WebView

**Problem:**

If I display different data records, the respective PDF should be displayed.

**Question:**

How do I hand over the file path from JavaFX to JavaScript.

JavaFX Code to show the PDF

```js
public void handleShowPDF(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws MalformedURLException {

        try {
            eWebView.setVisible(true);

            webEngine = eWebView.getEngine();
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/jScript/index.html");
             webEngine.load(url.toString());
             }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.print("error " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

HTML Code for calling JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>PDF Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top-bar">
    <button class="btn" id="prev-page">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Prev Page
    </button>
    <button class="btn" id="next-page">
        Next Page <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </button>
    <span class="page-info">
        Page <span id="page-num"></span> of <span id="page-count"></span>
      </span>
</div>

<canvas id="pdf-render"></canvas>

<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code

```js
// How do I get the path value from JavaFX 
const url = '../docs/pdf.pdf';

let pdfDoc = null,
    pageNum = 1,
    pageIsRendering = false,
    pageNumIsPending = null;

const scale = 1.5,
    canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Render the page
const renderPage = num => {
    pageIsRendering = true;

    // Get page
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
        // Set scale
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        const renderCtx = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport
        };

        page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
            pageIsRendering = false;

            if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
                renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
                pageNumIsPending = null;
            }
        });

        // Output current page
        document.querySelector('#page-num').textContent = num;
    });
};

// Check for pages rendering
const queueRenderPage = num => {
    if (pageIsRendering) {
        pageNumIsPending = num;
    } else {
        renderPage(num);
    }
};

// Show Prev Page
const showPrevPage = () => {
    if (pageNum <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum--;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};

// Show Next Page
const showNextPage = () => {
    if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};

// Get Document
pdfjsLib
    .getDocument(url)
    .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    console.log(pdfDoc);

    document.querySelector('#page-count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    renderPage(pageNum);
})
    .catch(err => {
        // Display error
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'error';
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
        document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(div, canvas);
        // Remove top bar
        document.querySelector('.top-bar').style.display = 'none';
    });

// Button Events
document.querySelector('#prev-page').addEventListener('click', showPrevPage);
document.querySelector('#next-page').addEventListener('click', showNextPage);
```

Comment: Have you tried [`webEngine.excecuteScript(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get the point how webEngine.executeScript(...) could help. My problem is, how i have to write the call in JavaFX and the receive in JavaScript

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking. You say you have a file path in JavaFX, and you want to "hand it over to Javascript". So you can "hand it over" by defining a function in javascript that takes the path as a parameter (and does whatever you need), and then call it from JavaFX via `webEngine.executeScript(...)`. And just pass a call to the function with the file path embedded as the parameter.